# ASP.NET MVC 3 Tutorials desperately needed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am a university student who is trying to create a conference scheduler (in ASP.NET MVC 3) that has the ability for the user create conference sessions based on dates and times and for attendees to add sessions to their personalized timetable.

Can anybody please please please recommend any tutorials / websites / blogs that demonstrate how to create something similar that I can use as a starting point to both create this project / learn how to add the features I require?

Your help would be greatly appreciated:)

Samantha

Answer (score 7):

For me, a real world sample is always the most useful where to start :

http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

There is a real world sample there called **The Contoso University Web Application**

Also, look at the [ASP.NET MVC Dynamic Universal Map of Resources](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/08/11/asp-net-mvc-dynamic-universal-map-of-resources.aspx) :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416514(VS.98).aspx

The following conference session videos are great the start with as well :

**MVC 3 – 101 by Scott Hanselman** : 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/DevDays/DevDays-2011-Netherlands/Devdays002

**ASP.NET MVC 3 @:The Time is Now by Phil Haack** : 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM03

**ASP.NET + Packaging + Open Source = Crazy Delicious by Scott Hanselman** : http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/PDC/PDC10/FT01

And there are so many out there on [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com)

As a blog suggestions, [My Blog](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/) is better than [Phil Haack's](http://haacked.com) :D

Answer (score 0):

Not specific tutorials for just this project, but there are great MVC3 tutorials to get you up to grips on http://www.asp.net/mvc.

I think you will have to search a long time to find a so specific tutorial, if it even exists.

Answer (score -1):

Nerd dinner should be a good starting point for your project.
It was recently updated to the MVC3

[NerdDinner on codeplex](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/)

Also look at the [Asp.net MVC section](http://www.asp.net/mvc) for more related resources

Answer (score -2):

How about this well known one: http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm. Although it is from an MVC1 book the basic principals have not changed in MVC3.

Comment: NewsFlash! Lots of things have changed from MVC 1 and there are many resources for MVC 3. Worst thing to suggest is a resource from ASP.NET MVC 1.

Comment: Agree with tugberk, looking at that tutorial is not a good idea.  Some things will still work, but many others are obsolete now